# Rotating a plane around a pivot point located at one of it's corner points and around an axis...

Tags: trigonometry

I have a plane and want to rotate around a pivot point located at one of its corner points and around a axis which is orthogonal to its diagonal at a given angle. So I have a right triangle along the diagonal of the plane.

[image]

How could i find the angle of another right triangle also orthogonal to the plane along one oft the planes sides? So how are the angle related two each other? I guess it has something to do with the dot product of the two vectors of the adjacent sides of both triangles, but couldnt find out how.

I hope the image describes it better then my words :)
Thanks.